# AMPscript concat while setting variable

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I'm facing an issue where I'm not sure if this would be the correct way to define my var. Here's the code :

```
%%[var @product1,
@product2,
@product3,
@product4,
@product5,
@product6,
@marca,
@rows,
@counter,
@i,
@product

SET @marca = AttributeValue("Marca__c")
SET @counter = 6
SET @rows = LookupRows("Product2","Marca__c","%%marca%%")

FOR @i=1 to @counter DO
SET @row = (@rows,@i)
SET @concat("product",@i) = Field(@row,"Product_Image_Link_c__c")
NEXT @i
]%%`
```

I need to have a var that changes according to i, in other languages it's usually pretty simple but I'm very confused in AMPscript.

is  `SET @concat("product",@i) = Field(@row,"Product_Image_Link_c__c")` the correct way?

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: This guide got you covered: https://gortonington.com/dynamically-creating-variables-in-ampscript/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few syntax errors in your code, let's sort them out while getting to creating dynamic variable names. I will use your code as a basis for this:

```ampscript
%%[
var @product1,
@product2,
@product3,
@product4,
@product5,
@product6,
@marca,
@rows,
@counter,
@i,
@product

SET @marca = AttributeValue("Marca__c")
SET @counter = 6
/* So far, so good */
```

Here comes the first issue. This was your line: `SET @rows = LookupRows("Product2","Marca__c","%%marca%%")`
You can't reference variables like this. `%%marca%%` notation is only to be used when you want to print this DE field inline, like `<h1>Hello %%marca%%</h1>`.

Instead you should use:
`SET @rows = LookupRows("Product2","Marca__c",@marca)`
*/

```ampscript
FOR @i=1 to @counter DO
SET @row = (@rows,@i)
SET @concat("product",@i) = Field(@row,"Product_Image_Link_c__c")
NEXT @i
]%%
```

In the above code, you can't just concat (also, you are mixing variable declaration and function call like you do): `SET @concat("product",@i) = Field(@row,"Product_Image_Link_c__c")`

Instead, you should replace the line with this one:

`SET @FieldSet = TreatAsContent(CONCAT('%','%[SET @product', @i, ' = Field(@row,"Product_Image_Link_c__c")]%', '%'))`

As per the [article](https://gortonington.com/dynamically-creating-variables-in-ampscript/) by [Gortonington](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/12730/gortonington).